# aws ebs volumes best practice

Tags: amazon-ec2

If I have 400 5GB files stored on a aws ebs magnetic st1 volume(s) that will have random read access am I better off using a single 2TB volume or 4 500GB volumes? On a 'regular' computer I believe I would see better performance from 4 separate magnetic disks than a single one (I'm not talking about a RAID, just having my randomly accessed files spread between 4 disks). I'm assuming that the heads or 4 separate disks could be randomly accessing sectors faster than one disk, and that 4 i/o channels to the CPU would be better than one. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Do my 'regular' computer assumptions apply to ebs volumes that are attached to an ec2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon EBS volumes are virtualized, so you cannot assume certain physical characteristics.

More relevant is a throughput limit for each Amazon EC2 instance that would impact total throughput to *all* EBS volumes combined.

If performance is important, then consider using **Provisioned IOPS** drives that guarantee a level of throughput per-volume. If you are using *many* PIOPS volumes, then also make sure your instance is *EBS Optimized* to ensure sufficient throughput to all volumes.

As always, the correct answer is to **test the performance yourself** to ensure your configuration is giving you the required performance. In doing so, make sure you "warm-up" the volumes by reading/writing to the volumes first before measuring, which will actually read/write the blocks to a physical disk. This is because blocks are only allocated to a disk when they are actually used, so the first access will be slower than subsequent access.